# Apply function conditionally

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe like this:

```
experiment iter  results
    A       1     30.0
    A       2     23.0
    A       3     33.3
    B       1     313.0
    B       2     323.0
    B       3     350.0
 ....
```

Is there a way to tally results by applying a function with conditions. In the above example, that condition is all iterations of a particular experiment.

```
A   sum of results (30 + 23, + 33.3)
B   sum of results (313 + 323 + 350)
```

I am thinking of "apply" function, but can't find a way to get it work.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There are a lot of alternatives to do this. Note that if you are interested in another function different from `sum`, then just change the argument `FUN=any.function`, e.g, if you want `mean`, `var` `length`, etc, then just plug those functions into `FUN` argument, e.g, `FUN=mean`, `FUN=var` and so on. Let's explore some alternatives:

`aggregate` function in base.

```
> aggregate(results ~ experiment, FUN=sum, data=DF)
  experiment results
1          A    86.3
2          B   986.0
```

---

Or maybe `tapply` ?

```
> with(DF, tapply(results, experiment, FUN=sum))
    A     B 
 86.3 986.0
```

---

Also `ddply` from plyr package

```
> # library(plyr)
> ddply(DF[, -2], .(experiment), numcolwise(sum))
  experiment results
1          A    86.3
2          B   986.0

> ## Alternative syntax
> ddply(DF, .(experiment), summarize, sumResults = sum(results))
  experiment sumResults
1          A       86.3
2          B      986.0
```

---

Also the `dplyr` package

```
> require(dplyr)
> DF %>% group_by(experiment) %>% summarise(sumResults = sum(results))
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

  experiment  sumResults
1          A        86.3
2          B       986.0
```

---

Using `sapply` and `split`, equivalent to `tapply`.

```
> with(DF, sapply(split(results, experiment), sum))
    A     B 
 86.3 986.0
```

---

If you are concern about timing, `data.table` is your friend:

```
> # library(data.table)
> DT <- data.table(DF)
> DT[, sum(results), by=experiment]
   experiment    V1
1:          A  86.3
2:          B 986.0
```

---

Not so popular, but doBy package is nice (equivalent to `aggregate`, even in syntax!)

```
> # library(doBy)
> summaryBy(results~experiment, FUN=sum, data=DF)
  experiment results.sum
1          A        86.3
2          B       986.0
```

---

Also `by` helps in this situation

```
> (Aggregate.sums <- with(DF, by(results, experiment, sum)))
experiment: A
[1] 86.3
------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
experiment: B
[1] 986
```

If you want the result to be a matrix then use either `cbind` or `rbind`

```
> cbind(results=Aggregate.sums)
  results
A    86.3
B   986.0
```

---

`sqldf` from sqldf package also could be a good option

```
> library(sqldf)
> sqldf("select experiment, sum(results) `sum.results`
      from DF group by experiment")
  experiment sum.results
1          A        86.3
2          B       986.0
```

---

`xtabs` also works (only when `FUN=sum`)

```
> xtabs(results ~ experiment, data=DF)
experiment
    A     B 
 86.3 986.0
```