# How to calculate mean?

Tags: r, mean

I would like to calculate the temperature mean for each country. I have a data.frame of 10 countries and their respective temperatues. As you see:

```
    Country amp_temperature
1   France  17,6
2   France  17,2
3   Italy   17,4
4   Slovenia    18,6
5   Slovenia    18,3
6   Estonia 23,8
7   Estonia 22,7
8   Estonia 21,5
9   Estonia 23,1
10  Estonia 23,7
11  Estonia 23,8
12  Estonia 22,9
13  Estonia 23,6
14  Norway  21,4
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What language do you want to use for this?

Comment: not sure what the question here.. algorithm, actual code? what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your data is `DF`, `aggregate` function should be one good alternative.

```
> aggregate(amp_temperature~Country, FUN=mean, data=DF)
   Country amp_temperature
1  Estonia         23.1375
2   France         17.4000
3    Italy         17.4000
4   Norway         21.4000
5 Slovenia         18.4500
```

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16657546/1315767) which gives several anternatives to do what you need.

Comment: @Rinot you might want to accept an answer as the correct one, click in the tick mark right below to the score.

Answer (score 1):

```
tapply(mydata$amp_temperature,mydata$Country,mean)
```