# Data split and sapply

Tags: r, split, return, sapply

I'm new to the `R` language and I'm having some difficult to calculate the returns of my dataset for every `Identification`.

I have a very large dataset of monthly observations grouped like so:

```
Code      Subset   Identification   Names        Times       Value      %   
100       1001        10011         .....        201012       10        40 
100       1001        10012         .....        201012       11        60 
100       1002        10021         .....        201012        7        30 
100       1002        10022         .....        201012       13        70 
..... 
100       1001        10011        .....         201301       11        45 
100       1001        10012        .....         201301       15        55 
100       1002        10021        .....         201301        9        33 
100       1002        10022        .....         201301       17        67
```

I need to write a function that can calculate the monthly rate of returns for every `Identification`. Then, I need to aggregate the values so calculated in the upper level of "subset" (with a mean weighted "%").

I've changed the format of the vector `times` to `year-month` i.e. "%Y-%m" in this way:
`as.yearmon(as.character(Data$Times), format = "%Y%m")`

and I've tried to calculate the returns for every `Identification` using `split` and `sapply`, like this: 
`xm <- split(Data, Identification)` 
`Retxm <- sapply(1:length(xm), function(x) returns(Value))`

The output i had using the function above is like this:

```
        [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]          
[1,]            NA            NA            NA            NA        
[2,]  1.605198e-03  1.605198e-03  1.605198e-03  1.605198e-03 
[3,] -1.190902e-02 -1.190902e-02 -1.190902e-02 -1.190902e-02 
[4,]  3.318032e-03  3.318032e-03  3.318032e-03  3.318032e-03
```

The output is not many clear, so i would have on the row the Times and on the header the `Identification`.

Thank you so much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/averaging-column-values-for-specific-sections-of-data-corresponding-to-other-col/11562850#11562850

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code generator. Please show what you have tried.

Comment: @Roland idea alert: Random R code generator! Lorem ipsum for R if you will.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik But it has to generate code that doesn't return an error. ;)

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657512/apply-function-conditionally/16657546#16657546) also offers a starting point .

Comment: I think questioners should demonstrate that they have done some searching before we go out and attempt to augment their efforts.

Comment: I'm sorry but i've two preliminary problem to write the R' code, i tried in this way:

1) i've some problems to set up the times vector with the format "%Y-%m": as.character(format(attr(dati, "Times"), "%Y-%m"));

2) i don't know how i can write the function to calculate the returns because i need to calculate them for every "Identification".

The only way i've found to set up the problem is with the "split", like this:
split(c(dati$Value),as.factor(dati$Identification))

I hope that i've better explained the problem.
Thaks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal dataset which is similar:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(id=sample(c("10011", "10012", "10013"), 6, replace=TRUE),
                  d1=rep(c(201012, 201101), each=3),
                  v1=ceiling(20*runif(6))
                  )
```

As to your first question, you can't format an object as `Date` in base `R` unless you specify the day in addition to the month and year.
To handle dates which are specified by month & year you could use:

```
library(zoo)
df1$d1 <- as.yearmon(as.character(df1$d1), format="%Y%m")
```

As to the second part of the question it's unclear to me what sort of calculation you're trying to perform. Following your methods you can indeed `split` the `data.frame` and do something with each element e.g. get the sum of the elements in the `v1` column:

```
l1 <- split(df1, df1$id)
sapply(1:length(l1), function(i) sum(l1[[i]]$v1))
```

*Edit* My Java's not working so can't add comment. Still not clear what you're trying to do. Would be better if you could spell it out with a working example; try editing your original question if able to do so.

Comment: Thank's for all the advices!
the calculation i'm trying to do is like this: 
Value(t)-Value(t-1)/Value(t-1) to calculate the monthly returns for every Identification. 
Afther this i need to aggregate the montly returns for every Subset.
Returns of the subset are calculated weigthing the Identification returns for the column "%".