# How to scale a variable by group

Tags: r, r-factor, standardized

I would really appreciate your help in this question.
I have the following dataset and I would like to create a new variable which would contain the standardized values (z distribution) per level of a given factor variable.

```
x <- data.frame(gender = c("boy","boy","boy","girl","girl","girl"),
                values=c(1,2,3,6,7,8)) 
x

   gender values
1    boy      1
2    boy      2  
3    boy      3
4   girl      6
5   girl      7
6   girl      8
```

My aim is to create one new variable which will contain the z-values calculated separately for each factor level (for boys and for girls).

And another question. I mainly would like to create a variable with the z-values. Would it be similar if I would like to apply another function and for example calculate distribution in quantiles per factor level?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `scale` with `ave` and `transform`:

```
> transform(x, z_score=ave(values, gender, FUN=scale))
  gender values z_score
1    boy      1      -1
2    boy      2       0
3    boy      3       1
4   girl      6      -1
5   girl      7       0
6   girl      8       1
```

`aggregate` is also useful

```
> aggregate(values ~ gender, scale, data=x)
```

And there are a lot of ways using `ddply` from plyr, `tapply`, `data.table`. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16657546/1315767)

Comment: You don't need `with` inside `transform`.

Answer (score 0):

The question how to create z scores has already been answered.

Here's a way to calculate quantiles for each factor level:

```
with(x, tapply(values, gender, FUN = quantile))
# $boy
#   0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
#  1.0  1.5  2.0  2.5  3.0 
#
# $girl
#   0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
#  6.0  6.5  7.0  7.5  8.0
```