# Subsetting data frame by factor level

Tags: r, function, for-loop, subset

I have a big data frame with state names in one colum and different indexes in the other columns.
I want to subset by state and create an object suitable for minimization of the index or a data frame with the calculation already given.

Here's one simple (short) example of what I have

```
m
  x   y
1 A 1.0
2 A 2.0
3 A 1.5
4 B 3.0
5 B 3.5
6 C 7.0
```

I want to get this

```
m
  x y
1 A 1.0
2 B 3.0
3 C 7.0
```

I don't know if a function with a for loop is necessary. Like

```
minimize<-function(x,...)
for (i in m$x){ 
do something with data by factor value 
apply to that something the min function in every column
return(y)
}
```

so when you call

```
minimize(A)
[1] 1
```

I tried to use %in% but didn't work (I got this error).

A%in%m
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'A' not found

When I define it it goes like this.

```
A<-c("A")
"A"%in%m
[1] FALSE
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you need to use this subsetting BE CAREFUL!! FIRST check if there's any NA couse min function will mess with it and give you wrong minimum values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(y ~ x, m, min)

  x y
1 A 1
2 B 3
3 C 7
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I am so new at R it took me 2 hours searching for  this answer here, nobody used aggregate. In fact I cuouldn't find the other post with those alternatives before now

Answer (score 3):

Use `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(.~x, FUN=min, dat)
  x y
1 A 1
2 B 3
3 C 7
```

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16657546/1315767) to get some other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
require(data.table)
m <- data.table(m)

m[, j=min(y), by=x]
#    x V1
# 1: A  1
# 2: B  3
# 3: C  7
```