# apply function in vectorization of a vector inside another vector

Tags: r

year
1999    1999    1999    2003    2003    2005    2005    2005    2005    2007    2009    2009    2009

A1
15    7 24  6   65  5   89  56  21  15  19  7   23

Above table shows a data frame. I want to have a vector, lets say "median1" which has the median of those values in a1 corresponds to each year. And I know that with a for loop it is easy but I am trying to find a 'vectorized' based solution.

Comment: Please, take your time and make an effort to edit your question. You can find [some alternatives here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16657546/1315767)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ave` which is an R base function. Combining `ave` with `transform` you'll get a pretty nice output. Consider `dat` is your data.frame

```
> transform(dat, Median= ave(a1, year, FUN=median))
  year a1 Median
1 1999 20   15.0
2 1999 15   15.0
3 1999 11   15.0
4 2003 11    7.0
5 2003  3    7.0
6 2007 89   40.5
7 2007 25   40.5
8 2007 56   40.5
9 2007 12   40.5
```

If you only want a vector consisting of medians per each year you can do:

```
> with(dat, ave(a1, year, FUN=median))
[1] 15.0 15.0 15.0  7.0  7.0 40.5 40.5 40.5 40.5
```

Answer (score 1):

with `data.table` package if your `data.frame` is called `DF`

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(DF)
DT[,median(a1),by='year']
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can do this:

```
foo <- data.frame(
  year=c(1999,1999,1999,2003,2003,2005,2005,2005,2005,2007,2009,2009,2009),
  A1=c(15,7,24,6,65,5,89,56,21,15,19,7,23))
by(foo$A1,foo$year,median)
```

Strictly speaking, the result will not be a `vector`, but you can fix that:

```
as.vector(by(foo$A1,foo$year,median))
```

`by()` is always helpful when you want to do an operation *by* groups.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me, but it seems like you want the median of each year?  If so...

```
## set up the data
> year <- c(1999,1999,1999,2003,2003,2005,2005,2005,2005,2007,2009,2009,2009)
> A1 <- c(15, 7, 24, 6, 65, 5, 89, 56, 21, 15, 19, 7, 23)
> dd <- data.frame(year, A1)

## solution
> xx <- c(do.call(cbind, lapply(split(dd, dd$year), function(x) median(x$A1))))
> names(xx) <- unique(dd$year)
> xx
1999 2003 2005 2007 2009 
15.0 35.5 38.5 15.0 19.0
```