# Sum up equal variables in data frame in R keeping values in different columns

Tags: r, sum

I would like to sum equal values in a given data set. Unfortunately I do not really have a clue where to begin with, especially which function to use.
Lets say I have a data frame like this

```
count<- c(1,4,7,3,7,9,3,4,2,8)
clone<- c("aaa","aaa","aaa","bbb","aaa","aaa","aaa","bbb","ccc","aaa")
a<- c("d","e","k","v","o","s","a","y","q","f")
b<- c("g","e","j","v","i","q","a","x","l","p")
test<-data.frame(count,clone,a,b)
```

Problem is that there are lots of repetitive single values wich need to be combined in one (all the "aaa" and the two "bbb").
So I would like to aggregate(?) all equal values in column "clone", summing up the "count" values taking the value for "a" and "b" from the clone with the highest count.

My final data set should look like:

```
count<- c(39,7,2)
clone<- c("aaa","bbb","ccc")
a<- c("s","y","q")
b<- c("q","x","l")
test<-data.frame(count,clone)
```

Do you have a suggestion which function I could use for that? Thanks alot in advance.

EDIT: Sorry, I was too tired and forgot to put in the "a" and "b" cloumn, which makes quite a difference since aggregating just after clone and count drops these two columns with essential information, I need in my final data set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(count~clone, FUN=sum, data=test)
  clone count
1   aaa    39
2   bbb     7
3   ccc     2
```

Also [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16657546/1315767) for further alternatives.

Comment: Thanks Jilber for the link! I didnt ask correctly and left out an important part. I've edited my question and would be very happy about a hint ;)

Comment: okay this was rather easy, I just had to add the columns into the aggregate expression like this: > aggregate(count~clone+a+b, FUN=sum, data=test)!

Answer (score 2):

This can be handled with `tapply`:

```
tapply(count, clone, sum)
# aaa bbb ccc 
#  39   7   2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with ddply from `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(test,.(clone),function(x) sum(x$count))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library('dplyr')
summarize(group_by(test, clone), count = sum(count))
```