# How can I aggregate using sum and min in R?

Tags: r

I'm having troubles to aggregate differents shops by date and SKU.

My sample data is like this:

```
Date        SKU    Quantity Price 
2010/01/01  52144    1        4.00
2010/01/01  87548    5        0.50
2010/01/01  47852    3        1.99
2010/01/01  52144    4        3.80
2010/01/02  87548    1        0.55
```

And I'm trying to use the function agreggate to sty like this:

```
 Date        SKU    Quantity Price 
2010/01/01  52144    5        3.80
2010/01/01  87548    5        0.50
2010/01/01  47852    3        1.99
2010/01/02  87548    1        0.55
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16657546/1315767) you can find some guidelines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this easily with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, Date, SKU) %>% 
    summarize(Quantity = sum(Quantity), Price = min(Price))
#         Date   SKU Quantity Price
# 1 2010/01/01 47852        3  1.99
# 2 2010/01/01 52144        5  3.80
# 3 2010/01/01 87548        5  0.50
# 4 2010/01/02 87548        1  0.55
```

And also with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Quantity = sum(Quantity), Price = min(Price)), by = .(Date, SKU)]
#          Date   SKU Quantity Price
# 1: 2010/01/01 52144        5  3.80
# 2: 2010/01/01 87548        5  0.50
# 3: 2010/01/01 47852        3  1.99
# 4: 2010/01/02 87548        1  0.55
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this "simmultaneously" using `aggregate`, `dplyr` or some other function/package? (e.g. the sum of one column and the minimum of another)

Comment: Not sure about aggregate, but `dplyr` and `data.table` are much easier

Answer (score 4):

When dealing with this kind of things, I've found that the [`sqldf` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html) is a great tool. Let's say your data is stored in a data frame called `df`. You can use a `SELECT` instruction to get what you need:

```
sqldf("select Date, SKU, sum(a.Quantity) as Quantity, min(a.Price) as price
       from df as a
       group by Date, SKU")
```

You can use standard SQL instructions to manipulate, filter or aggregate data stored in data frames (which `sqldf` reads as if they were tables)

Answer (score 4):

cough base cough

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Date        SKU    Quantity Price 
2010/01/01  52144    1        4.00
2010/01/01  87548    5        0.50
2010/01/01  47852    3        1.99
2010/01/01  52144    4        3.80
2010/01/02  87548    1        0.55")

tmp <- within(dat, {
  sums <- ave(Quantity, list(Date, SKU), FUN = sum)
  mins <- ave(Price, list(Date, SKU), FUN = min)
})

tmp[!with(tmp, duplicated(cbind(Date, SKU))), ]

#         Date   SKU Quantity Price mins sums
# 1 2010/01/01 52144        1  4.00 3.80    5
# 2 2010/01/01 87548        5  0.50 0.50    5
# 3 2010/01/01 47852        3  1.99 1.99    3
# 5 2010/01/02 87548        1  0.55 0.55    1
```

Comment: Wasn't gonna vote on any of these, but +1 for making me laugh with the coughs.