# Summing over particular columns of data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, pivot-table

I would like to do use some of Excel's pivot table functionalities in data frames of R. I can do what I want with some length coding, but I am wondering if there is an easy way to do it.

Assume I have the following data frame:

```
name<-c("Mexico","France","Chile","Germany","Sudan") 
continent<-c("Am","Eur","Am","Eur","Afr") 
population<-c(1000,2000,3500,2500,2000) 
countries<-data.frame(name,continent,population)
```

I want to get a new data frame only with columns continents and population, where the population is summed over countries. So I want this get this one:

```
> continents
continent population
1 Am 4500
2 Eur 4500
3 Afr 2000
```

Any easy way for it?

Comment: `library(dplyr);countries %>% group_by(continent) %>% summarise(population=sum(population))`

Comment: Look at `?aggregate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(population~continents, data=countries, FUN=sum)
  continents population
1        Afr       2000
2         Am       4500
3        Eur       4500
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16657546/1315767) for further alternatives

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted.