# Summing down a column with multiple categories

Tags: r, aggregate

If I have a data frame that looks like

```
dat<-data.frame(val= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),category= c("A","B","c","A","B","c","D"))
dat

  val category
1   1        A
2   2        B
3   3        c
4   4        A
5   5        B
6   6        c
7   7        D
```

I'd like to AVERAGE by the category so the output looks like

```
A  2.5
B   3.5
C    4.5
D     7
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16657546/1315767)

Comment: Downvote for no research effort `r average by category` in google - first result is http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/how-to-summarize-data-by-group-in-r which would give you multiple answers.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way would be to use `tapply` as follows:

```
tapply(dat$val, dat$category, FUN = mean)
```

Note that if you have missing values you'd want to amend it to ignore those in the calculation of the mean

```
tapply(dat$val, dat$category, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

see ?tapply

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on from your end. If I copy your `dat` argument exactly, on a fresh `R` session, and then run `tapply`, I get   `2.5 3.5 4.5 7.0`.