# Get minimum grouped by unique combination of two columns

Tags: r

What I'm trying to achieve in R is the following: given a table (data frame in my case) - I want to be get the lowest price for each unique combination of *two* columns.

For example, given the following table:

```
+-----+-----------+-------+----------+----------+
| Key | Feature1  | Price | Feature2 | Feature3 |
+-----+-----------+-------+----------+----------+
| AAA |         1 |   100 | whatever | whatever |
| AAA |         1 |   150 | whatever | whatever |
| AAA |         1 |   200 | whatever | whatever |
| AAA |         2 |   110 | whatever | whatever |
| AAA |         2 |   120 | whatever | whatever |
| BBB |         1 |   100 | whatever | whatever |
+-----+-----------+-------+----------+----------+
```

I want a result that looks like:

```
+-----+-----------+-------+----------+----------+
| Key | Feature1  | Price | Feature2 | Feature3 |
+-----+-----------+-------+----------+----------+
| AAA |         1 |   100 | whatever | whatever |
| AAA |         2 |   110 | whatever | whatever |
| BBB |         1 |   100 | whatever | whatever |
+-----+-----------+-------+----------+----------+
```

So I'm working on a solution along the lines of:

```
s <- lapply(split(data, list(data$Key, data$Feature1)), function(chunk) { 
        chunk[which.min(chunk$Price),]})
```

But the result is a 1 x n matrix - so I need to `unsplit` the result. Also - it seems very slow. How can I improve this logic? 
I've seen solutions pointing in the directions of the `data.table` package. Should I re-write using that package?

**Update**

Great answers guys - thanks! However - my original dataframe contains more columns ( Feature2 ... ) and I need them all back after the filtering. The rows that do not have the lowest price ( for the combination of Key/Feature1 ) can be discarded, so I'm not interested in their values for Feature2 / Feature3

Comment: With what logic the values of the other columns are to be taken? If for instance `Feature2` has different values for the same key-feature1, which value must be included in the output?

Comment: The value belonging to the lowest price. So this thing needs to work as a row filter. So the 'whatever' of AAA-1, AAA-2, BBB-1. Rest of the rows can be discarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% group_by(Key, Feature1) %>%
         slice(which.min(Price))
```

Comment: Great works - but I need to get all columns back in the result. I simplified the example a bit. In reality the data contains more columns, which I need in the result.

Answer (score 3):

Since you referred to `data.table` package, I provide here the solution using that package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.(Price=min(Price)),.(Key, Feature1)] #initial question
setDT(df)[,.SD[which.min(Price)],.(Key, Feature1)] #updated question
```

df is your sample data.frame.

Update: Test using `mtcars` data

```
df<-mtcars
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.SD[which.min(mpg)],by=am]
   am  mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs gear carb
1:  1 15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.60  0    5    8
2:  0 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.25 17.98  0    3    4
```

Answer (score 1):

The base R solution would be `aggregate(Price ~ Key + Feature1, data, FUN = min)`

Comment: Very elegant - but I need to get all columns back in the result. I simplified the example a bit. In reality the data contains more columns, which I need in the result.

Comment: Do you mean you want the minimum value back in your original dataframe? If that's the case use `ave(data$Price, data$Key, data$Feature, FUN = min)`.

Comment: No - see the updated question - I only want the row with the lowest value ( for the unique combination of Key + Feature1 ) - but with all the original values. I tried your code and it returns only 3 columns: Key, Feature1 and Price - but I also need all the other original columns.

Comment: Are the data in other columns identical within each combination of Key and Feature1? If not do you want their mean?

Comment: It's irrelevant. If the row does not contain the minimum price ( for the combination of Key + Feature1 ) the row can be discareded. It needs to work as a filter on the rows. - thanks for all your effort btw.

Comment: Ah I see. Well the `dplyr` solution by jeremycg looks good. A `data.table` one would to do the same would be  `setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD, min), by = list(Key, Feature1)]`, provided you did `data <- data.table(data)`.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear - I didn't expect my simplification of the problem would result in not giving enough information to come up with a solution.

Comment: @choff: I already posted a solution from `data.table` package. If you think that is not working, please let me know.

Comment: @user227710 I see your update now. Your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Using R base `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(Price~Key+Feature1, min, data=data)
  Key Feature1 Price
1 AAA        1   100
2 BBB        1   100
3 AAA        2   110
```

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16657546/1315767) for other alternatives.