# Aggregating two columns in R dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R called food:

```
foodID   calories   fat    protein

 123       0.5      0.4     0.9
 432       0.65     0.3     0.7
 123       0.32     0.6     0.5
 983       0.82     0.2     0.6
```

and I'm trying to **average** up the **calories and protein column** by **foodID**.

I tried:

```
cal_pro <- aggregate(food[2,4], list(food$foodID), function(df) mean(df))
```

But it appears that i can't select the columns to be applied the mean function by food[2,4]? Could anyone help me out on this.

Comment: Find more alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16657546/1315767)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply function conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657512/apply-function-conditionally)

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, you can just `group_by` and `summarize`:

```
food %>%
    group_by(foodID) %>%
    summarize(calories_average = mean(calories),
              protein_average = mean(protein))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  foodID calories_average protein_average
   <int>            <dbl>           <dbl>
1    123             0.41             0.7
2    432             0.65             0.7
3    983             0.82             0.6
```

Rather than specifying each variable, you can use `summarize_at` to select multiple variables to summarize at once. We pass in 2 arguments: the variables to summarize, and a list of functions to apply to them. If the list is named, as it is here, then the name is added to the summary column as a suffix (giving "calores_average" and "protein_average":

```
food %>%
    group_by(foodID) %>%
    summarize_at(c('calories', 'protein'), list(average = mean))
```

`summarize_at` also allows you to use various helper functions to select variables by prefix, suffix, or regex (as shown below). You can learn more about them here: `?tidyselect::select_helpers`

```
food %>%
    group_by(foodID) %>%
    summarize_at(vars(matches('calories|protein')), list(average = mean))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the formula method

```
aggregate(cbind(calories, protein) ~ foodID, food, mean)
```

---

Or using the OP's code, it should be c(2, 4), because if we do `2, 4`, it is selecting the 2nd row of 4th column by row/column indexing

```
aggregate(food[c(2, 4)], list(food$foodID), mean)
```

EDIT: Based on @RuiBarradas comments

Comment: I believe it should be `c(2, 4)` not `2:4`.

Comment: @akrun doing [2:4] applies the mean function to the third column as well isn't it? Does this mean i will have to remove the third column later on?

Comment: @Maxx Sorry i thought you want a sequence of columns

Comment: @Maxxx  Do you expect anything else in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.table` package-

```
> setDT(dt)[,list(avg_calorie=mean(calories),avg_protein=mean(protein)),by=foodID]
```

**Output-**

```
    foodID avg_calorie avg_protein
1:    123        0.41         0.7
2:    432        0.65         0.7
3:    983        0.82         0.6
```