# Sum values grouping by another column in R

Tags: r

Having the following `dataframe`:

```
A   | B
--------
abc | 5
def | 2
abc | 4
ghi | 2
def | 1
```

How can I sum `B` grouping by `A`?

Sample output:

```
A   | B
--------
abc | 9
def | 3
ghi | 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `aggregate(B~ A, df1, sum)`  or `dplyr` `df1 %>% group_by(A) %>% summarise(B = sum(B))` or using `rowsum` `rowsum(df1$B, df1$A)`

Comment: [Take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16657546/1315767)