# Is there an R function for summing variables tied to an identifying variable?

Tags: r

I have the data format:

```
          id   OB03A OB03B
          1     1     1
          1     0    NA
          1     1    NA
          1     0    NA
          2     0    NA
          2     1    NA
```

I am trying to add up all of the values of OB03A for each id, so for id 1 the sum should be 2, and for 2 it should be 1, etc. Is there a function that can do this? I have tried messing around with lapply and counting functions, but that feels too complicated. Is there a better solution?

The final dataframe should be one to one id to OB03A sum:

```
         id   OB03A OB03B
          1     2     1
          2     1    NA
          3     1    NA
```

Comment: You could use the dplyr functions group_by() and summarize()

Comment: Read the manual page for `aggregate`. What do you want to do about OB03B? Sum? First value? Last value? Drop?

Comment: [Some alternatives here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16657546/1315767)

Comment: @dcarlson I will most likely drop it, I am still not sure if it is good enough data to use seriously. I will probably remove the whole vector though. Sorry for leaving it in.

Comment: The apply function conditionally is perfect for this, thank you!

Comment: `aggregate(. ~ id, d, function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE), na.action = NULL)`